# file conversion every after 10 minutes cronjob

Tags: php, ffmpeg, cron, cron-task

I have added a cron job to execute a script after every 10 minutes , the script checks if the any new file is uploaded to directory, if there is a new file then it converts the video file to a small size like i have given in the command ..

Below is the code i have tried , everything is working , i tried adding the email functionality as well and it works, but not executing ffmpeg command

```
$last = (int)file_get_contents('timestamp.txt');
file_put_contents('timestamp.txt', time());
$files = glob('videos/*.mp4');
$files = array_filter($files, function($file) { 
    return filemtime($file) > $last; 
});

if ($files) {
    foreach ($files as $sfile) {
        $sfile = str_replace('videos/', '', $sfile);
        $video = 'videos/'.escapeshellcmd($sfile);
        $sixty = "videos/250/".escapeshellcmd($sfile);
        $cmdform = "ffmpeg -i $video -vf scale=250:140 $sixty";
        $do = `$cmdform`;
    }
}
```

One more thing is that it converts the files with static name  like if i give "videos/1.mp4" then it works but does not work in foreach loop.

and command to set cron job

```
*/10 * * * * wget http://mywebsite.com/coding.php
```

Much thanks.

Comment: Do some `echo` in the `foreach` loop to check is it getting iterated, also print  `$do` to check what is the response.

Comment: It is not printing anythinks, thanks. but what is the solution?

Comment: instead of `echo` try `error_log`, & check the error log. I guess in the first iteration something went wrong which stops the iteration. First have to find the issue, then think of the solution.

Comment: Everything is working, i checked using putting the url in web browser and it executes the command, but its not working in cron job.

Comment: `# m h dom mon dow user  command` I think you forgot to add `user`. Try `*/10 * * * * root wget http://mywebsite.com/coding.php`

Comment: I updated teh cron command , but no luck.

Comment: can not move to chat.

Comment: I can not move to the chat.

Comment: Check the cron log `/var/log/syslog` to see if there any clue. Also check whether `wget` is installed in your server. Try running `wget http://mywebsite.com/coding.php` command & see do u get any errors

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam Thank you.

Comment: I guess you manage to solve your issue. May I know what was the issue

Comment: It worked using shell_exec($cmd), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute to external command , u can make use of php bellow cmd

```
exec('cmd')
```

Eg:

```
<?php    
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

Output : your machine name

In your case it will be

```
...
...
...
$cmdform = "ffmpeg -i $video -vf scale=250:140 $sixty";
$do = exec($cmdform);
```

I hope this is useful

Comment: any error did u got ? which operating system ur trying ?

Comment: try var_dump(exec($cmdform)) ;